# MDX parameters in SSRS with large data set

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, mdx-query

I have a lot of data in a cube and I have a query that works perfectly.

I need to make this smaller and the user needs to add the Number and Year and the data displayed because there is just too much information.

I have added a parameter on the number field and also year field.
But once I build this in `SSRS` the query takes 15 minutes.
In SQL if you add a where clause and let the user enter the number it will reduce the amount of time the query takes. Will this also work with a cube.

Here is the `MDX` script:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Ontvangen Verbruik]
     ,[Measures].[Gecorrigeerd Verbruik]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Aansluitingen].[EAN].[EAN].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[EDSN Manier Van Levering].[EDSN Manier Van Levering].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[EDSN Gebruiker Type].[EDSN Gebruiker Type].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Bron].[SJV Bron].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Hoog].[SJV Electra Hoog].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Laag].[SJV Electra Laag].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Totaal].[SJV Electra Totaal].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Straat].[Aansluiting Straat].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer Toevoeging].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer Toevoeging].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Postcode].[Aansluiting Postcode].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Plaats].[Aansluiting Plaats].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Gas].[SJV Gas].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Additionele informatie meteropnames].[Bron Meetgegevens Nederlands].[Bron Meetgegevens Nederlands].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Collectieven].[Collectief Naam].[Collectief Naam].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Collectieven].[Collectief ID].[Collectief ID].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Klanten].[Klant Nummer].[Klant Nummer].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Klanten].[Klant Naam].[Klant Naam].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Meetdatums].[Meetdatum Jaar].[Meetdatum Jaar].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Telwerken].[Telwerk].[Telwerk].ALLMEMBERS*
        [VerbruikEinddatums].[VerbruikEinddatum].[VerbruikEinddatum].ALLMEMBERS*
        [VerbruikStartdatums].[VerbruikStartdatum].[VerbruikStartdatum].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_VALUE
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    (@AdditioneleinformatiemeteropnamesBronMeetgegevensNederlands
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      (@AansluitingenEAN
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        StrToSet
        (@MeetdatumsMeetdatumJaar
         ,CONSTRAINED
        ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Meteropnames]
    )
  )
)
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Just some tips to improve the query of this cube. Some direction or help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a huge cross join on rows - hence the complexity and time taken to process. Can you delete any of those dimensions from the cross join without upsetting stakeholders?

There are three nested sub-selects - you could try moving those directly in to the `ROWS` clause?

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Ontvangen Verbruik]
     ,[Measures].[Gecorrigeerd Verbruik]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        StrToSet( @AansluitingenEAN ,CONSTRAINED ) *
        [Aansluitingen].[EDSN Manier Van Levering].[EDSN Manier Van Levering].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[EDSN Gebruiker Type].[EDSN Gebruiker Type].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Bron].[SJV Bron].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Hoog].[SJV Electra Hoog].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Laag].[SJV Electra Laag].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Electra Totaal].[SJV Electra Totaal].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Straat].[Aansluiting Straat].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer Toevoeging].[Aansluiting Huis Nummer Toevoeging].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Postcode].[Aansluiting Postcode].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[Aansluiting Plaats].[Aansluiting Plaats].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Aansluitingen].[SJV Gas].[SJV Gas].ALLMEMBERS*StrToSet(@AdditioneleinformatiemeteropnamesBronMeetgegevensNederlands,CONSTRAINED)*
        [Collectieven].[Collectief Naam].[Collectief Naam].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Collectieven].[Collectief ID].[Collectief ID].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Klanten].[Klant Nummer].[Klant Nummer].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Klanten].[Klant Naam].[Klant Naam].ALLMEMBERS*
        StrToSet( @MeetdatumsMeetdatumJaar, CONSTRAINED ) *
        [Telwerken].[Telwerk].[Telwerk].ALLMEMBERS*
        [VerbruikEinddatums].[VerbruikEinddatum].[VerbruikEinddatum].ALLMEMBERS*
        [VerbruikStartdatums].[VerbruikStartdatum].[VerbruikStartdatum].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_VALUE
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM [Meteropnames]
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Another simplification I'd suggest is do you need the `DIMENSION PROPERTIES`?
I'd suggest deleting this section to see if it affects the speed, or breaks the results?

[image]